# I can't recognize this font family

Tags: fonts, html5

Can anyone help to recongnize what fonts were used to create this html5 sheet? Especially I would like to know what font was used for description and comments. Thanks.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/antoniolupetti/3894233282/sizes/o/in/photostream/

Comment: Is this any help? http://www.identifont.com/

Comment: Unfortunately... not. I tried to search through Linotype without any success so far.

Comment: I believe the font to be "Helvetica" after using the tool.  If you can confirm this, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) identified the font used for the title and tags as [Unit Rounded Pro Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/unit-rounded/pro-bold). The rest of the text looks like [Trebuchet MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet_MS).

Answer (score 0):

I used the online tool [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) to try and figure out what the font was.  After answering the questions, I saw a font that it suggested and I believe it to be the font in that picture.

The font is a glossy version of [Helvetica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica).

The gloss was probably created by the program used to make the cheat sheet.  The font was used and the image effects in the program created the gloss.

---

As for the image as a whole.  I think (aside from the logo) it is just various modifications of the Helvetica font.

Comment: Erik Spiekermann would kill himself after reading this.